# How to toggle class of clickable image

Tags: jquery

Our users have a table showing their titles. (They're contained in a datatable, if that matters).  The idea is to simply have an image that they can click to toggle published or not.  The below code *does change the image* as expected, but does *not change the class*.

I've also tried addclass/removeclass, but with the same results.  Am I missing something obvious, or am I doing something completely wrong?

```
<img class="title_publish" src="IsNotPublished.png">'
<img class="title_unpublish" src="IsPublished.png">


$('.title_publish').live('click', function () {
    this.src="IsPublished.png";
    this.toggleClass("title_publish");
    this.toggleClass("title_unpublish");
} );

$('.title_unpublish').live('click', function () {
    this.src="IsNotPublished.png";
    this.toggleClass="title_publish";
    this.toggleClass="title_unpublish";
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.title_publish').live('click', function () {
    this.src="IsPublished.png";
    $(this).toggleClass("title_publish");
    $(this).toggleClass("title_unpublish");
} );
```

Comment: Interesting....that works.  Why is the $() required in one case, but not the other?

Comment: toggleClass is jquery function so could not called with this which is javascript object. src is attribute of anchor and javascript knows it. this.src = "IsPublished.png"; could be written in jQuery $(this).attr('src', 'IsPublished.png');

Comment: You should use jQuery always instead of mix/match. Would help resolve problems in the future, and it's generally better practice. See my answer

Comment: Yes, if you read comments I told the syntax for setting src in jQuery but sometimes we need to mix them e.g how you would gett list of attributes of an html elements using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

### You can take care of both button behaviors in one function.

Here's how you do it:

First, toggleClass is a function, so use it as one; btw it can take several space-seperated classes.

Second, for the sake of using jQuery throughout the code always, use `$(this).attr('src', newsrc);` to change the source of the image. I also added a condition that checks if `Not` should be added to the image name. Here's how I do it:

```
$('.title_publish, .title_unpublish').live('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("title_publish title_unpublish");
        $(this).attr("src", "Is" + ($(this).hasClass('title_publish') ? '' : 'Not') + "Published.png");
    } );
```

Use the above instead of the two clicks you binded in your code - this is one code that will always take care of both button behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to toggle between two classes (title_publish and title_unpublish) you can use the toggle class with both classes. For example:

```
$(this).toggleClass('title_publish title_unpublish');
```

jquery will know with your click which class need to show.

see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FyPKg/16/)